# How to add a custom Manager inside a pop-up screen in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am trying to add a custom window in blackberry but before this i am trying to add a custom label in that popup screen for my satisfaction that i can add or cant . so at the time when i am adding that i am facing the problem of IllegalArguementException error , so can you please tell me how can i solve that problem . i am doing like this .

see this is my MYScreen class which i am using to add pop-up . so pop-up is added when ever i clicked that press button , which is added in the Screen .

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
    private ButtonField btn;

public MyScreen()
    {        
        setTitle("MyTitle");

        btn = new ButtonField ("press");
        btn.setChangeListener(this);

        add(btn) ;
    }

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if ( field == btn )
    {       
    Dialog.inform("hello");

    pop_manager manager_object = new pop_manager(0);

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( new up_pop_test( manager_object ) );               
    }
}
}
```

so in this i have added , new_up_pop_test class which is :

```
public class up_pop_test extends PopupScreen
{
public up_pop_test( pop_manager delegate)
{
    super(delegate);

    add(delegate);
}
}
```

and pop_manager is :

```
public class pop_manager extends Manager
{
protected pop_manager(long style)
{
    super(style);
}

protected void sublayout(int w, int h) 
{
    Field f = getField(0);
    layoutChild( f , w/3+w/3 , 50 ) ;
    setPositionChild ( f , w/33 + w/33 , w/67+w/104 );

    setExtent(w,h);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do as much work as you were trying to...

All you need is a **PopupScreen**, which you can customise at will, just like a normal screen.

```
public class MyPopup extends PopupScreen  {

    public MyPopup() {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager());
        LabelField infoLabel = new LabelField("Here is a label in a popup");
        add(infoLabel);   
    }
}
```

In order to call it, all you need to do is push like a normal screen.

```
  UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyPopup());
```

You cannot gain control over the **Dialog** class, these are for simple operations like informing the user or asking a question, and are standardised

Comment: sorry sorry , basically i want to add my custom manager , in this screen .

Comment: Then swap super(new VerticalFieldManager()); with super(new pop_manager(0));

Comment: i have done this , but the again i am facing a new problem that .... when i am trying to add some field in that manager ... it is not displayed , but when i am painting something inside that manager ... it is displayed !

Comment: I'm getting illegal argument exception.